# System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'datasource'.'

Tags: c#

im having a problem with this everytime i run my code.. heres my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("DataSource=SQLSERVER;Bar_login; Integrated Security = True");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Bar_login where username = '" + txtuser.Text + "' and password ='" + txtpass.Text + "' ", con);
sda.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Login Succesfully");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username and Password");
}
```

it succesfully run but after the login process.. theres an exception

> unhandled.."System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'datasource'.'".

can anyone help?

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be a space between "Data" and "Source" in your connection string. The keyword is "Data Source" and not "DataSource".